# Getting formatted string from NSTextView

Tags: swift, nstextview

I am creating an OSX app with `NSTextView` inside `NSScrollView`. Using the `FormatMenuItem` I can modify the text in that `NSTextView` to Bold, italic etc. But when I get the values using `(NSTextViewOutlet.String)` I cannot get the modified string, that is the string contain bold and italic characters.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please post a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can help you.

Comment: The formatted characters are in the `attributedString` property.

Comment: thanks eric. using attributedString i get the values from NSTextView. But i can't Store it in core data with datatype String. I need to store the attributedString to coredata and retrieve it and display in NSTextView.

Comment: I see two ways: either encode the attributed string to data (with NSKeyedArchiver for example) and sync this data, then unpack for reuse; or extract the attributes and their locations in the attributed string and sync them + the raw string, then recreate the attributed string from these elements. Both solutions require work on your part but are not hard to implement. I would use the first solution, personally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using below code solve my problem.and i use NSTextField instead of NSTextView.

```
let str = txt_outlet.attributedStringValue
```

Comment: In your OP you asked about *getting* some value. You answer shows how to *set* some value. Seems to me like some parts were missing from you answer.